# Plot daily data of a stock

Tags: r-markdown, stock

I'm a little unsure where to ask this question but hope I got it right! If not, please correct me.

I am doing a lab in R Markdown (in school) where I have downloaded the historical (daily) values of the prices of one stock for a period that covers ten years, and then I am going to plot the daily data of the stock.

My question is what daily data of a stock is? Since the csv-file with the historical values contains the values *Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Adj Close och Volume* I am a little unsure on what it is I should really plot - my spontaneous thought is the closing prices during this 10-year period. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually stock price is referred *Adj Close* since it takes into account events like stock splits and dividends.

So basically, if you see line chart of stock prices, you usually see something like that under the hood:

```
plot(x = my_data$Date, y = my_data$`Adj Close`, type = 'l')
```

However, *Open*, *High*, *Low*, *Close* can be used to make visualizations with more accent on daily movements (in case of daily data). Check out candlestick charts abd OHLC charts. It can be achieved with *quantmod* or *plotly* packages for instance:

```
quantmod::chartSeries(my_data)

plotly::plot_ly(my_data, x = ~Date, , open = ~Open, close = ~Close, high = ~High, low = ~Low type="ohlc")
```

Comment: Thank you! I did this with the following code:

`
MSFT <- quantmod::getSymbols("MSFT", auto.assign = FALSE)
quantmod::chartSeries(MSFT)
`

However I got the error message
 ## Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
##   method            from
##   as.zoo.data.frame zoo

Do you know why?

Comment: This is not error. It's just notification that two packages have functions with the same name.